# ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'. Angular ngx-mask

Tags: angular

I installed a package ngx-mask and when i tested on ie it doesnt work. It gets ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'. I attached the code. I modified polifills. So the problem is for IE. On Chrome it works. I used ngx-mask for formatting numbers. I will appreciate any help.

```js
<input placeholder="street" formControlName="street" mask="99" />
```

```html
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

 /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


 //import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: can you Please attach screen short of your console here so that I can find actual error ?

Answer (score 1):

String.includes isn't supported on IE. However, you can easily polyfill this method by following [this official mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)

Comment: I used that, but it doesnt work. I included in pollyfils.ts file

Comment: Ok, and in your tsconfig file, what's your target?

Comment: the target is es5